# Java Eclipse: Programmatically import plug-ins and fragments

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to programmatically import a .jar in my workspace as I do when I use the menu:
Import -> Plug-in development -> Plug-ins and Fragments.

Here I find the code for import a java project:

> IProjectDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(
>           new Path("PROJECT_PATH/.project")); 
>    IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(description.getName());
>   project.create(description, null); 
>   
> project.open(null);

But I don't have .project on .jar file. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are close, do all of that and then create an `IFile` object and read the Jar file into the `IFile` object. The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_filesystem.htm?cp=2_0_10_1) has some helpful snippets of code to show you how to do this.